# why always vc_redist DetectCondition getting failed in wix code(.wxs)

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.7

!--  OR Detect existing version of VC ++ 2015-2019 x64 libraries -->
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Id="GetVC14X64Exists" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64" Result="exists" Variable="vc14x64Exists" Win64="yes"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Id="GetVC14X64Version" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64"  Result="version" Variable="vc14x64Version" Win64="yes" /

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"  Id="GetVC14X86onX64Exists" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86" Result="exists" Variable="vc14x86onx64Exists" Win64="yes"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"  Id="GetVC14X86onX64Version" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86"  Result="version" Variable="vc14x86onx64Version" Win64="yes" Format="raw" />
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"  Id="GetVC14X86onX86Exists" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86" Result="exists" Variable="vc14x86onx86Exists" Win64="no"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"  Id="GetVC14X86onX86Version" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86" Result="version" Variable="vc14x86onx86Version" Win64="no"/>
```

Always DetectCondition fails for equal versions Anybody suggests here?

Comment: Thi is the DetectCondition added DetectCondition="(vc14x64Exists AND (vc14x64Version &gt;= v$(var.VC_redistToInstall))) OR (vc14x86onx64Exists AND (vc14x86onx64Version &gt;= v$(var.VC_redistToInstall))) OR (vc14x86onx86Exists AND (vc14x86onx86Version &gt;= v$(var.VC_redistToInstall)))">

Comment: these are namespaces included:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'
   xmlns:bal='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension'
   xmlns:util='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension'
   xmlns:dep='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DependencyExtension' 
     xmlns:netfx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension' >

Comment: We would need to see the log in %TEMP% to see what the variables are getting set to, and what `$(var.VC_redistToInstall)` is getting resolved to. I don't see the point in trying to look at keys under WOW6432Node, just specify Win64="no" and only use the normal paths.